# why javascript function stops working after returning back?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have made a rotating slider in javascript and css. Javascript function makes it rotating. When i first time load the page it works fine but when i navigate to some other page and then return back, the js function is called but the slider does not stop rotating on mouse hover. I have made a js function that when mouse hovers on div the rotation stop, when it leaves the function is called again.Here is my js code

```
var timer;
        window.onload = function()
        {
            myTimer();
        };

var $i=1;
 function myTimer(){
                timer=setInterval(function(){
                    if($i<6){
                        closeTab();
                        openTab($i);
                        $i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {$i=1;}
                },2000);
            }
 closeTab();

            var selectedSlider ;
            function closeTab()
            {
                var $this = $('#accordion > li');
                //$width=$(window).width();
                //$this.stop().animate({'width':'110px'},500);
                $this.stop().animate({'width':'7%'},500);
                $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
                $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
            }
            function openTab(id)
            { 
                var $this = $('.bg'+id);                                        
                //$this.stop().animate({'width':'450px'},500);
                $this.stop().animate({'width':'70%'},500);
                $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
                $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
            }

openTab(1);
            $(function() {
                $('#accordion > li').hover(
                function () {
                    console.log("in mouse hover");
                    var $this = $(this);
                    selectedSlider = $this.attr("class").replace("bg", "");
                    closeTab();
                    openTab(selectedSlider);
                    clearInterval(timer);
                },

                function () {

                }
            );
            }); 
$('#accordion > li').mouseleave(function(){
                console.log("in mouse leave");
                myTimer();
            });
```

Comment: Something like this happened to me once because the browser was caching the javascript (the wrong way).

Comment: so David what solution did you implement to solve that?

Comment: I changed the caching settings in the .htaccess file on my Apache server. @jailedabroad

Comment: @David ok ,but the above js code is inline means it lies in index.php file. i am caching other files with extensions css,js, and other files. But index.php loads every time so this js code should load every time.

Answer (score 0):

As @David said browser was caching the javascript, so your code for hover effect is not work as you put it in such a way, that when js file will call then hover event is fire but here js file is already cached.

You may try this, instead of using hover function anonymously put it inside `window.onload`.

Comment: have you cleared your browser cache before implementing changes?

Comment: Is your code or project live or any live demo so I can review it?

Comment: On mouse hover have you check what id is passed to openTab function. `selectedSlider = $this.attr("class").replace("bg", "");
 openTab(selectedSlider);`

Comment: no i am not checking the id. i think that does not make any difference